# Oraclize send fee in oraclize_query

Tags: parity, oracles

I know that only the first call to oraclize_query is free but i don't know how to send the small fee requested.
Can you give a code sample ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Marco from Oraclize here.

The fee is taken automatically from the smart contract balance when you call oraclize_query. There are two possible cases then:

- The smart contract has already the funds in its balance before oraclize_query gets called
- The smart contract has zero balance, but then the transaction which execute the function with the oraclize_query call must carry some value to pay the fee. A reminder: the function then **must have** the payable modifier in order to be able to accept value.

You can see an example [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oraclize/ethereum-examples/master/solidity/KrakenPriceTicker.sol)

If you want to know exactly how much the call is going to cost you:

```
uint oraclizeFee = oraclize_getPrice(datasource)
```

where you specify the datasource from the list that you can find on the [docs](http://docs.oraclize.it/)

If you have any more questions, feel free to ask also on [our gitter channel](https://gitter.im/oraclize/ethereum-api)